the judgement of the Prime number
#task:input a number ,then determine if it is a prime number.
1.question:how can I optimize my code ,and when I run this code ,I find that some prime numbers get the answer "No".
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a;
    int i;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    for (int i = 2; i <= a; i++) {
        if (a % i == 0) {
            printf("No");
            break;
        }
    }

    if (i == a) {
        printf("Yes");
    } else {
        printf("No");
    }

    return 0;
}

how can I optimize my code ,and when I run this code ,I find that some prime numbers get the answer "No".

Note that you don't need to search up to N-1; up to and including
ceil(sqrt(N)) is sufficient.
If N is composite, then one factor is not larger than √N and the other
is not smaller than √N).
After you've checked for 'divisible by 2', you could check only the odd
numbers.
If you check for 'divisible by 3' outside the loop, then all bigger
primes have the form 6K±1 for an integer K starting at K equal to 1.
Limiting the search range gives a radical speedup even when N is just in
the thousands, let alone much bigger.
Using 'odds only' does 1/2 the work; using 6K±1 does 1/3.

Note that you shouldn't search with i <= a as when i == a, a % i == 0 so the answer "No" is printed before the post-loop code prints "Yes".  Also, you should end you printed output with a newline — it is a good practice to get into from the beginning.

I've added the tag [tag:primes] to your question — you should look for other questions with that tag (type [c] [primes] in the search box on SO).

Do you get some compiler warnings? Like "Using variable i without assigning a value first"? If not, you should increase your warning level. For GCC and clang you can use -Wall -Wextra -pedantic. If you got a warning, then you should never just ignore it unless you really understand what it means

Please note that because you have introduced a new i variable in your loop which shadows the i declared at the beginning of the function, the i referenced later in the function  outside the loop's scope is uninitialized, and the comparison has undefined behavior.
Ideally we would break this out into a separate function.
#include <stdbool.h>

bool is_prime(int n) {
    for (int d = 2; d * d <= n; d++) 
        if (n % d == 0) return false;

    return true;
}

Even more ideally, you'd implement the Sieve of Eratosthenes, especially if you're checking to determine if multiple numbers are prime.

For prime numbers it is much better to use an unsigned integer type instead of a signed integer type because prime numbers can not be negative.
This for loop:
for (int i = 2; i <= a; i++) {

shall be declared at least like:
for ( i = 2; i <= a; i++) {

That is you shall not introduce a new variable i within the block scope of the for loop.
Each number is divisible by itself. So this for loop:
for(int i = 2;i<=a;i++) {
    if(a%i == 0) {
        printf("No");
        break;
    }
} 

will always output "No" when i is equal to a.
The program can look for example the following way:
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    while (1)
    {
        printf( "Enter a number (0 - exit): " );

        unsigned int n;
        if (scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0) break;

        int prime = n % 2 == 0 ? n == 2 : n != 1;

        for (unsigned int i = 3; prime && i <= n / i; i += 2)
        {
            prime = n % i != 0;
        }

        printf( "%u is %sprime\n", n, prime ? "" : "not " );
    }
}


Although there are already good answers, I would like to post an answer that is more suitable for beginners of C language.

First of all, 1 is not a prime number.

Secondly, there are some logic error corrections in your code: your code only determines whether it is a prime number after the loop ends, which will cause "NO" to be output early during the loop. It should be judged inside the loop whether there is a factor. If there is a factor, "NO" is output directly. After the loop ends, it is judged whether the last number has been traversed. If so, "YES" is output.

Then loop optimization: you can just loop to the square root of a, because if there is a factor greater than the square root of a, then there must be a factor smaller than a.

Finally for prime numbers, it is better to use unsigned integer type instead of signed integer type because prime numbers cannot be negative.


#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    int i;
    int is_prime = 1; // Assume a is prime
    
    if (a <= 1) {
        is_prime = 0; // Numbers less than or equal to 1 are not prime
    } else {
        for (i = 2; i <= sqrt(a); i++) {
            if (a % i == 0) {
                is_prime = 0; // If a factor exists, it's not prime
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    if (is_prime) {
        printf("Yes");
    } else {
        printf("No");
    }
    
    return 0;
}

